# Efficient exception handling for threads in java

Tags: java

How do we implement efficient exception handling when using threads.

I have a main program which creates 3 threads. How do we handle the exceptions for the exceptions thrown during the execution of thread?

Can we use the try/catch block or uncaughtexception. If so, can you please share some samples.

```
public class MyThreadTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      Thread newThread = new Thread(new ThreadWithException());

      // Add the handler to the thread object
      newThread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler(){

          @Override
          public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {

           System.out.println("ERROR! An exception occurred in " + t.getName() + ". Cause: " + e.getMessage());
          }
      });

      newThread.start();
  }
}

/**
 * This thread throws a custom exception in its run method.
 */
class ThreadWithException implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
    throw new RuntimeException("Application Specific Exception!!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Either you can use:

- [Thread#setUncaughtExceptionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29) to specify some code that is run when an exception is thrown (outside of normal program flow), or:
- [ExecutorService#invokeAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) to run all of your blocks, and inspect the returned list for [Future#get()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28%29)'s throwing of `ExecutionException`.  Another option is [CompletionService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html), but this is slightly harder to use for such a simple case.

Comment: Can't we use the traditional try/catch instead of the above specified methods? if so, what is the disadvantage of using try/catch?

Answer (score 0):

You can use try / catch block strategy:

```
    Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //..thread code 
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        };
```

It is easy to implement but in case of exception main thread of your application will never know what happened inside of child thread.

Better method would be to spawn threads using ExecutorService (as mentioned by FauxFaux). This will allow you to easily pass information about the error to main thread. Besides that, using ExecutorService allows you to write less code. You won't have to manage threads in your code but leave it for ExecutorService instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response. i do not have main thread and child threads. i have a java program which is creating 3 threads.I am trying to handle the exceptions in the respective threads. like any other program, since the java program is calling the threads, will the exceptions not come up to the main program and then we will get the knowledge of exceptions. Hope i am clear. Please let me know your thoughts. looking forward for your response..

Comment: I 'll try to explain a few things and ask more questions :)
1. When you start even the simplest Java application a thread is created. I call it a main thread. There is no such thing in Java like running code "outside" of thread.
2. When you create Thread and start() it then one usually says that child thread was created and started. I assume that you do it 3 times in your app.
3. Second part of your comment is not clear to me (Starting from * like any other program...*) I guess that you don't want to inform anyone about exceptions. In such case try / catch strategy is enough for you

Comment: hi Johnny,Thanks for the details. As of now, my main thread(program) is not getting notified about any exceptions occurred in the child threads. in the catch block of the respective child threads, the exceptions are logged out to a log file. which gives me complete details of the individual threads. if i want the main thread( calling program) to be intimated about any exceptions in child thread, i will go for the Uncaughtexception handlers. i have mentioned a simple program which does the uncaught exception handler logic.Please take a look at it.

Comment: instead of "throw new RuntimeException("Application Specific Exception!!");" can we use "throw new Exception("");" .

Answer (score 0):

beacuse , recently, I have write a program with about 3 threads in order to fill a lot data from mysql and mongoDb to ElasticSearch. I share u my code.

I use java.util.concurrent.Executors.

First I have a main class. It calls

```
public void start() throws Exception {
    this.logger.info("Main: Start the worker manually");
    schedulerThreadPool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(this.maxNumberOfThread);

    for (int i = 0; i < this.maxNumberOfThread; i++) {
            Worker worker = new Worker();
            long delay = i * this.sleepBetweenTaskStart;
            schedulerThreadPool.scheduleAtFixedRate(worker, delay, this.minTimeBetweenEachTask, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

And Worker implements Runnable and get Thread Id by below code.
`this.threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();`
And just try catch in each Worker. Everything works normally.

```
@Override
public void run() {
        try {
            do...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
```